# OnClickListener not working for first item in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a problem with creating a GridView-based calendar. Here is the Grid:

[image: GridView Calendar]

This is supposed to be a calendar populated with events, so I have my adapter implement OnClickListener and I set that listener for every button in the calendar. It works perfectly for every single button **EXCEPT** the first one(in this case number 30). When I click it just doesn't work, but when I click on another button after I have attempted to click on the first one, it performs the click for the first one just before performing the click for the other button.

I've scanned about 10 pages of relevant questions and have not found someone to have this problem. Help please!

As asked, here is the getView function of my code:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (row == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell, parent, false);
            holder.gridCell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
            holder.multiDayEvent = (EventLengthView)row.findViewById(R.id.eventLengthView);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        int calendarGridHeight = (calendarView.getHeight()-5)/(getCount()/7);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                calendarGridHeight);
        row.setLayoutParams(params);

        //Change the background drawable depending on the position in the calendar
        if ((position+1) % 7 == 0){
            holder.gridCell.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_button_selector_end_row));
        }
        if (getCount() - position < 8){
            holder.gridCell.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_button_selector_end_column));
        }
        if (position == getCount()-1){
            holder.gridCell.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_button_selector_end));
        }
        holder.gridCell.setOnClickListener(this);

        holder.gridCell.setTag(null);//clear tags

        // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING
        String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
        int theday = Integer.parseInt(day_color[0]);
        int themonth = Integer.parseInt(day_color[2]);
        int theyear = Integer.parseInt(day_color[3]);
        String date = DateFormat.format("dd/M/yy", new Date(theyear,themonth,theday)).toString();
        if ((!eventsMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsMap != null))
        {
            if (eventsMap.containsKey(date))
            {
                holder.multiDayEvent.SetMeasure(calendarView.getWidth()/7, calendarGridHeight);

                holder.multiDayEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //holder.singleDayEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Event event = (Event) eventsMap.get(date);
                holder.multiDayEvent.AddEvent(event);
                holder.gridCell.setTag(event);
            }
            else{
                //holder.singleDayEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.multiDayEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        // Set the Day GridCell
        holder.gridCell.setText(Integer.toString(theday));

        if (day_color[1].equals("GREY"))
        {
            holder.gridCell.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
        if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE"))
        {
            holder.gridCell.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE"))
        {
            holder.gridCell.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        row.setTag(holder);
        return row;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        Button gridCell;
        ImageView singleDayEvent;
        EventLengthView multiDayEvent;
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (view.getTag() != null){
            Event event = (Event)view.getTag();

            eventListView.setAdapter(new EventListAdapter(CalendarScreen.this, event));
            eventListViewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            eventListViewLayout.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        }
        else if (eventListViewLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

The onClick gets called for every gridcell EXCEPT the first one in the top left corner

Comment: Please put the code you have Used..

Comment: [Why didn't you try this example](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/)

Comment: my code is based on that example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. The problem was these lines:

```
ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null)
{
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell, parent, false);
    holder.gridCell = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell_button);
    holder.multiDayEvent = (EventLengthView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventLengthView);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

When putting instatiating the gridCell button there, somehow, it mixes up the click listener of the first position in the adapter. I ended up fixing it by just instatiating the holder in every pass, instead of getting it by tag (which is better for performance, but oh well). Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem.Keeping the setLayoutParams inside the if(view == null) clause worked out. You dont have to sacrifice view recyling in that way.

like :

```
 if(row == null){
   // inflate row
   row.setLayoutParams(params);
   //remaining code
 }else{
    holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
 }
 // everything else
```

I don't know why it works but it worked for me. I also noticed that all codes regarding the same issue in stackoverflow had also used setLayoutParams outside the if clause. This is my first time so i dont know if i can post this everywhere. Hope it helped .

Source : Lot of trail and error .

Comment: Worked for me and saved me a lot of time

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: It works. But this doesn't really make any sense. Why is it not working otherwise?

Answer (score 9):

Use your **OnClickListener()** in your activity after **.setAdapter()** method, not in your adapter class.

```
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(GridViewActivity.this, "" + position,
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. my problem has been solved by your solution.

Comment: This solution is best

Comment: This is much easier than trying to implement the OnClickListener in the gridview adapter

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I had also this issue (first cell in the gridview having delayed onclick).

In my case, I was using a (lightly customized) gridviews with dynamic sets of imageviews that I would make visible/gone and redraw the gridview. All imageviews where prepared beforehand and stored in the adapter.

Initially, I used notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter but this resulted in the delayed click problem for the first cell whenever the set was updated. I changed to just invalidating the gridview and now things are fine. Bear in mind that all my views are already created and stored in the adapter, its just the getview method that checks which ones are really visible.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.  The click event on the first item was significantly delayed.  I was already using notifyDataSetInvalidated().  **Using onItemClickListener() solved the issue**, although I still don't understand why the onClick listener on the individual items has this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Set onItemClickListener on the GridView object instead of setting onClickListeners on each button.

And I found another question with your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434411/android-onclicklistener-not-firing-in-gridview-2-2-only). Bounty maybe?

Comment: I also tried replacing the buttons with ImageViews(as I know the buttons block the onItemClickListeners of the GridView) but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After spending so many days, set layout params as follows..

```
if (view == null) {

        // call the user's implementation
        view = mInflater.inflate(mViewId, null);
        holder = createHolder(view);
        // we set the holder as tag
        view.setTag(holder);

        rlMainCell = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rlMainCell);
        rlMainCell.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) view.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._128sdp)));

    } else {
        // get holder back...much faster than inflate
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
```

it works absolutely fine to me