# OnClickListener not working for first item in GridView inside ViewPager

Tags: android-layout

Inside ViewPager, there is a gridview which has a grid of single choice answers with textviews and images. When i clicked on any answer, the textview should change its color to RED else WHITE. Its working fine for all the other answers except the **first one**. When i first clicked on first answer in gridview, it doesn't change the color, on second click it turns to RED, but then when i change the option, the RED color doesn't change to WHITE for first option. Look at the screen below,

Sorry Screen submission is not allowed for me as i am a new user...

Inside `GridFragment#OnActivityCreated()`:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long arg3) {

            currentPage = new TestTopics().getCuttentPage();

            tv = ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).lbl;                 

            if(selectedValues.containsKey(currentPage))
            {   

                selectedValues.get(currentPage).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                selectedValues.remove(currentPage);
                selectedValues.put(currentPage, tv);
                selectedValues.get(currentPage).setTextColor(Color.RED);



            }
            else
            {   

                selectedValues.put(currentPage, tv);
                selectedValues.get(currentPage).setTextColor(Color.RED);

            }               

        }
    });
```

`ImageAdapter#getView()` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    numTopics = mTopicList.getNumTopics ();
    ViewHolder holder;
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (convertView == null) { 

       int layoutId = R.layout.demo_pager_grid_item;
       LayoutInflater li =  ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
       childView = li.inflate (layoutId, null);

       holder.img = (ImageView) childView.findViewById(R.id.image);
       holder.lbl = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.title);

       childView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        childView = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) childView.getTag();
    }                

    if (childView != null) {
       // Set the width and height of the child view.
       childView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mCellWidth, mCellHeight));

       int j = position + mImageOffset;

       if (j < 0) j = 0;
       if (j >= numTopics) j = numTopics - 1;


       imageView = (ImageView) childView.findViewById (R.id.image);
       if (imageView != null) {
          Resources res = mContext.getResources ();
          int imagePadding = res.getDimensionPixelSize (R.dimen.grid_image_padding);

          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
          imageView.setBackgroundResource (R.color.background_grid1_cell);
          imageView.setPadding (imagePadding, imagePadding, imagePadding, imagePadding);
          imageView.setImageBitmap (mTopicList.getTopicImage (j));
          imageView.setTag (new Integer (j));


       }
       textView = (TextView) childView.findViewById (R.id.title);

       if (textView != null) 
       {           

                textView.setText(mTopicList.getTopicTitle (j)); 
                textView.setTag (mTopicList.getTopicTitle (j));
                holder.lbl.setTag(mTopicList.getTopicTitle (j));


       }
    }



    return childView;

}
```

I have seen this link : [OnClickListener not working for first item in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778228/onclicklistener-not-working-for-first-item-in-gridview), and follow the answer, but didn't get succeed on it...

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Yes, i have attached the updated code. Please refer it for solution.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check it!

Comment: It's not good to edit the question to add the solution; rather, post the solution as your own answer and accept it, so people can see this is solved, and you'll also get some points :)

Comment: Got your point Adinia, will take care of this next time.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> have solved it....
>
> I added `gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` in my following code :
>
> ```
> if(patternItems.containsKey(currentPage) && selectedValues.containsKey(currentPage))
>             {
>
>                 selectedValues.get(currentPage).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
>                 selectedValues.remove(currentPage);
>                 selectedValues.put(currentPage, tv);
>                 selectedValues.get(currentPage).setTextColor(Color.RED);
>                 **gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);**
>                 patternItems.remove(currentPage);                       
>                 patternItems.put(currentPage,tv.getText().toString());
>              }
>             else
>             {   
>                 selectedValues.put(currentPage, tv);
>                 selectedValues.get(currentPage).setTextColor(Color.RED);
>                 **gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);**
>                 patternItems.put(currentPage,tv.getText().toString());                                                                                              
>             }
> ```