# The imageView onClick event of first item in GridView can't work or delay

Tags: android, gridview, click, imageview

I've designed a GridView with custom item layout and there is one ImageView on the top-left corner, another ImageView on the top-right corner, a main ImageView and Text in the center.

I need to set the OnClickListener for both two ImageView on the corner and the OnItemClickListener for the adapter.

Everything worked fine but only the first item in the GridView can't trigger the OnClickListener. Can anyone solve this problem?

P.S. I found the first item ImageView's OnClickListener will trigger when I do the next action(e.g. Click other items)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    TagView tag;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = m_LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mydoc_grid_item, null);
        tag = new TagView(
                (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myDoc_GridItem_IV),
                (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myDoc_GridItem_TV),
                (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iViewAdd2Category),
                (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iViewDelete));
        v.setTag(tag);
    } else {
        tag = (TagView) v.getTag();
    }

    v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int) (180 * v
            .getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), (int) (180 * v
            .getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));


    tag.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    tag.image.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_DisplayItems.get(position)
                    .get("image").toString())));
    tag.text.setText(m_DisplayItems.get(position).get("text").toString());
    tag.iAdd2Category.setVisibility((m_IsEdit) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    tag.iDelete.setVisibility((m_IsEdit) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    if (m_IsEdit) {
        tag.iAdd2Category.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Click on image add 2 category");
            }
        });

        tag.iDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Click on image delete");
            }
        });
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: I found it's also happened when the item just contain image and button. The fist item of the GridView can't trigger the onClickListener for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer in this article.

[OnClickListener not working for first item in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11778228/1954594)

In my case:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    v = m_LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mydoc_grid_item, null);
    tag = new TagView(
            (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myDoc_GridItem_IV),
            (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myDoc_GridItem_TV),
            (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iViewAdd2Category),
            (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iViewDelete));
    v.setTag(tag);
} else {
    tag = (TagView) v.getTag();
}
```

just remove if else statement and the "tag" will be instantiated every time.

Comment: This solution has many performance issues, as you would be calling `findViewById` 4 times every time `getView()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing `OnClickListeners` and `OnItemClickListeners` for list's items doesn't work well.

In your case you should probably use multiple `OnClickListeners` on the different parts of your item and not use `OnItemClickListener` at all.

Comment: Hi fiddler, I just comment the `setOnItemClickListener` but the `setOnClickListener` for the first item's imageView still not work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this problem is, that Android calls getView() for the first item not only when the View is drawn, but also for Layout-Measuring! There is no way to differ within getView() between a measure call and a draw call. So when you first have a draw call, and at some later point a measure call you overwrite the onClickListener.
Actually it seems right to do so - since you do it every time, but i observed this behaviour. Maybe you set the clickListener and the system releases it after the getView call because the view won't be drawn... I didn't track that deep enough to assure.

Nevertheless it is a bad idea to recreate the view every time since it is VERY time expensive - your grid might not scroll smooth.

The solution is to write your own GridView as follows:

```
public class MyGridView extends GridView{
private GridAdapter adapter;


public MyGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setAdapter(GridAdapter adapter) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if(adapter!=null)
        adapter.setIsMeasureCall();
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}}
```

and implement the method setIsMeasureCall() in your GridAdapter. The method only sets a flag to true whenever it is called.
Then in your getView() method you check if it is a measure call and if this is true - you do not set the Listeners.

Make sure to set isMeasure to false at the end of your getView() method.

I hope everything is clear :)

For more information you can check out my homepage where I provide a full Android project that solves this problem.
http://simon.osim.at/projects/gridadapter/#TheSolution

Answer (score 0):

the selector file

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gridview_item_shape"></item>
     <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
</selector>
```

the item layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/griditem"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/grid_photo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gridview_item_select"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```